# What is the time complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

can someone tell me what is the time complexity of this algorithm? 
keep in mind: the second method (findMax) - run on the array based on the index that it gets, means that the method (findMax) doesn't run on all the array every time. 
I think that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n) but maybe I'm wrong.

```
public class Q2 {


public static int[] replace(int []a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
        if(i == a.length-1){
            a[i] = 0; 
       }

        int maxSubArry = findMax(a,i); 

          swap (a, i, maxSubArry);
    }
    return a; 

}


public static int findMax (int[]a, int i)
{
  //  i = i +1; 
    int tmp = 0; 
    for(i = i +1; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > tmp)
            tmp = a[i];
    }
    return tmp; 
    }


public static void swap(int[]a, int i, int maxSubArry)
{
    int temp = a[i]; 
    a[i] = maxSubArry; 
    a[i+1] = temp; 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `replace` method is more like bubble sort algorithm and the algorithm complexity is `O(n*n)`.

**AND** the initial value of `findMax` should be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. and the if statement is unnecessary in `replace`.

```
public static int[] replace(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        swap(a, i, findMax(a, i));
    }
    return a;
}


public static int findMax(int[] a, int i) {
    int tmp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (i = i + 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > tmp)
            tmp = a[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculation based on an example. Suppose your array passed to replace() has 10 elements (n = 10). So, the loop inside of replace() runs 10 times, and will call findMax 10 times. Because the loop inside findMax will only start running from i+1, the exact number of times it will run, based on the ten method calls, is (9-i) times:

```
 outer i | inner loop  | number of loops
=======================================
   0    | from 1 to 9 |     9
   1    | from 2 to 9 |     8
  ...   |  ...        |    ...
   8    | from 9 to 9 |     1
   9    | no loop     |     0
```

So your formula for the number of inner loops is 9 + 8 + 7 + ... + 1 = 45. That is roughly 1/2 n², and cleary more than n (which we assumed to be 10 in this example). As the big-o notation will disregard constant values, we can leave the 1/2 away, and simply say that the complexity is O(n²).

Answer (score 0):

Total complexity is O(n*n).For method findMax (int[]a, int i) in worst case it will take complexity of O(n) ,because in worst case it will search for 0 to last element as Max element present in last.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way the figure out the running time of algorithms like this is to notice that `findMax` runs over *at least half of the array, for at least half of its elements* (the first half).

To say the same thing in math: let **T(N)** be the total number of times that `findMax` inner loop runs:

**T(N) >= 0.5N * 0.5N**

**⇒ T(N) >= 0.25N²**

The running time of this algorithm is therefore at least **O(N²)**.

Then notice that `findMax` runs over *at most* the entire array for all of its elements, and that implies that the running time is at *most* **O(N²)**.