# Precise Θ notation bound for the running time as a function

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I'm studying for an exam, and i've come across the following question:

> Provide a precise (Θ notation) bound for the running time as a
>   function of n for the following function

```
for i = 1 to n {
    j = i
    while j < n {
        j = j + 4
    }
}
```

I believe the answer would be O(n^2), although I'm certainly an amateur at the subject but m reasoning is the initial loop takes O(n) and the inner loop takes O(n/4) resulting in O(n^2/4). as O(n^2) is dominating it simplifies to O(n^2).

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085863/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-algorithm/44086434#44086434

Comment: Your reasoning is not right for inner loop but it's complexity is quadratic. The inner loop run for N times then (N-1) then (N-2) etc so you get N*N => N^2

Comment: The inner loop is O([n-i]/4), because i can take values up to n, so cannot be ignored. But the final result would still be O(n^2)

Comment: Ahh okay! thank you! that made it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you proceed using Sigma notation, and obtain T(n) equals something, then you get Big Theta.

If T(n) is less or equal, then it's Big O.

If T(n) is greater or equal, then it's Big Omega.

[image]